# why do i need jdbc with sqlite java?

Tags: java, sqlite

if sqlite is self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine , why i can't just

```
Sqlitedatabase x = new SqliteDatebase(...);
```

and then use

```
x.CreateNewTable("table1","id int","name string");
```

Comment: Because, generally speaking, there is no such api, which is where JDBC comes in, it bridges the database and your program through common api layer

Answer (score 1):

The de-facto way to talk to databases in Java is through JDBC.  The driver used may then do this under the hood, but you are not supposed to.

Also sqlite is not written in Java.  If you want to use a database written in Java which can be embedded in your application, have a look at Apache Derby.